# how to avoid using GlobalScope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my code, I have a time-out functionality and I want to use a countdown timer but after a lot of research, I couldn't find similar functionality as a countdown timer in Kotlin coroutine (able to start, cancel and catch finish callback). Then I decided to use `GlobalScope.launch`. I know this is a bad solution but my code is working perfectly.

Here is my code

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            val timer = object: CountDownTimer(Constants.PAYMENT_TIMER, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}

                override fun onFinish() {
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        _eventFlow.emit(UIPaymentEvent.NavigateToBack)
                    }
                }
            }
            timer.start()
            collectPaymentIntentUseCase.invoke(currentPaymentIntent!!).onEach { result ->
               
                when (result) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        timer.cancel()
                        if (result.data?.exception == null) {
```

My question is how can find a 100% similar function to avoid using GlobalScope but be able to use the countdown timer (start, cancel,onComplete callback)?

Note: I am using GlobalScope.lanch to be able to emit UIPaymentEvent.NavigateToBack event to my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `CountDownTimer` here. Just use the `delay()` suspend function.

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    val job = launch {
        delay(Constants.PAYMENT_TIMER) // Wait for timeout
        _eventFlow.emit(UIPaymentEvent.NavigateToBack)
    }        
    collectPaymentIntentUseCase.invoke(currentPaymentIntent!!).onEach { result ->           
        when (result) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                job.cancel() // Cancel the timer
                if (result.data?.exception == null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callbackFlow` for listen your timer. I just code this editor. I hope it will be helpful.

```
fun timerFlow() = callbackFlow<UIPaymentEvent> {
    val timer = object : CountDownTimer(10, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}

        override fun onFinish() {
            CoroutineScope().launch {
                _eventFlow.emit(UIPaymentEvent.NavigateToBack)
            }
        }
    }
    timer.start()
    awaitClose()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines are launched inside a [CoroutineScope](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) which are similar to lifecycle for android. As such, Android automatically provide coroutine's scope for components like activity or fragment and bound them to theirs lifecycle.

While it's not recommended to use the global scope that starts and ends with android's process. There are no restriction on creating your own and limiting it to a specific view of time. Creating one starts its life and cancelling it stops all tasks inside.

In your case a countdown can be done with only coroutines. As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73578104/4681367) answer.

But without changing too much of your existing code you could reuse the `viewModelScope` that launched your timer to emit your event.

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    _eventFlow.emit(UIPaymentEvent.NavigateToBack)
}
```

Beware of the life of your scope. If the viewmodelScope is dead when the timer finish, the event will never be sent.